# Open data on public opinion polls (Gallup, PEW, and others)

Tags: data-request

Many international surveys are available for free:

- http://guides.library.yale.edu/pubopinion
- http://www.ciser.cornell.edu/info/polls.shtml

However, I didn't find the data from major poll agencies, such as Gallup and PEW, in a convenient format. Gallup, for instance, just offers summaries with its results, not the data itself.

Are there any interfaces (API) or datasets for this sort of aggregated poll results?

Answer (score 8):

All [Pew Research Center data](http://www.pewresearch.org/data/download-datasets/) is available for free use. But, you have to manually download each dataset.

Data for almost all other public opinion polling is stored at [the Roper Center](http://www.ropercenter.uconn.edu/CFIDE/cf/action/catalog/). These data are publicly searchable but not free to download.